# how knapsack problem will fit these weights in a theif bag as given below

Tags: algorithm

A theft robbing a store find n items; the ith element is worth vi dollars and weight wi pounds. He wants to take as valuable load as possible, but he can carry at most W pounds in his knapsack. The theft is allowed to take fraction of an item for the fraction of the weight and fraction of the value. Determine which items should he take? The goal is to maximize the value of items without exceeding the weight limit W of knapsack. item_1(price=30$, weight=10kg) , item_2(price=100$, weight=25kg) item_3(price=250$, weight=50kg), item_4(price=30$, weight=30kg) item_5(price=20$, weight=10kg), Knapsack capacity (W)=100kg

Comment: The sentence "The theft is allowed to take fraction of an item for the fraction of the weight and fraction of the value" makes the problem incomparably more easy than the usual knapsack problem. Each material has a price and a weight, and thus, a ratio "price per kg". You are limited in the total weight that you can carry; thus, what you want is to get the highest price per kg possible. Just pick the item with highest price per kg, and take as much as you can of this item. Then if you can still carry more stuff, take as much as you can of the second item with highest price per kg. Repeat.

Comment: Hi DarkReaper. I suggest you surround your code with a “code fence” == [3 backticks] YOUR CODE [3 backticks]. Check out this link: [Syntax highlighting for code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score 0):

Since the thief is allowed to take a fraction of an item for a fraction of the weight for a fraction of the value, you can use a greedy algorithm.

Sort the (value, weight) pairs by the (value / weight) descending. Then simply choose items from this list until you don't have space.